# Multiple nginx locations

Tags: nginx-config

I have multiple nginx locations via the same route

```
    location ~^/(v1) {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
   }

   location = /v1/smth {
   
   }
```

Does the proxy_pass would be applied for `/v1/smth`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginx [http-core-module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation describes the order of precedence when evaluating a match. Specifically:

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

In your example, `/v1/smth` therefore matches exactly with the second (empty) location block, and the `proxy_pass` is therefore not applied.